# Will meteor deploy overwrite the existing database?

Tags: database, meteor

First time I used `meteor deploy` everything was bundled and deployed perfectly.

Now I have made changes to the code that I want to deploy, but what happens to the content of the database when using `meteor deploy` again - will the content of the existing database be overwritten or will it remain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the contents of the database will not be overwritten. In fact, all meteor commands except `meteor reset` are non-destructive. See more about the [meteor command line](http://docs.meteor.com/#commandline).